# Pynput key press function call the event function problem

Tags: python, pynput

```
from pynput import keyboard as Kb
from pynput.keyboard import Controller as KbController
from pynput.keyboard import KeyCode as KbKeyCode
from pynput.keyboard import Key as KbKey
import time

Keyboard = KbController()

def on_press(key):
    Keyboard.press(KbKey.space)
    Keyboard.release(KbKey.space)
    print(str(key))
    KbListener.stop()


KbListener = Kb.Listener(on_press=on_press)
KbListener.start()
```

Look at the code above.
When i call the "Keyboard.press" function
The "on_press" event function is called.

In the above case,  when i pressed any key , space key is pressed repeatly

I want to prevent the "on_press" event function from being called when calling the "Keyboard.press" function.

How to avoid the above case?

Comment: Move `KbListener.stop()` to the top of the function, perhaps?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue....